# Ok cancel Dialog MVVM Pattern wpf.How can I do it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on a MVVM wpf application and I need to show various dialogs with ok cancel. I have seen few on the net but the look overcomplicated or may be its me struggling.

I Have noticed that many that use "IDialogService"

Can anybody point me to a link or has a snippet handy on how to implement a Dialog using a MVVM Pattern?

thanks a lot

Comment: Some context might help before I make an attempt at an answer: why are you using MVVM? Do you work in team or alone? Do you unit test your presentation layer? If yes, are you familiar with mocking frameworks?

Comment: What are you having troubles with? (Showing the dialog? Closing the dialog? Wiring up the dialog to your ViewModel? Other?) Also, are you using an MVVM framework, and if so, which one?

Comment: Sorry.I thought it was a very generic question.Hence no code. I am using Moq as Mocking framework.Ideally I would like to unit test it.In the real project at work I have a disconnected architecture using PL-SL-BL-DAL. I didnt want to confuse people or make the question to involved.I simply wanted and wants help on how to show a dialog using a MVVM pattern.I cannot use any of the framework out there.we use an in house one.Once I grab the context and can transfer it to my real project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

here is a barebones dialog with OK and Cancel buttons. I have included the XAML, View, and ViewModel:

**XAML:**

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestProject.Views.OKCancelDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    Title="Window Title"
    Height="300"
    Width="600"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    UseLayoutRounding="True"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">

    <Grid>
        <Button
            Name="OKButton"
            Content="OK"
            Height="23"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Margin="0,0,93,12"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            Width="75" 
            Click="OKButton_Click"
            IsDefault="True"
            Command="{Binding OKButtonCommand}" />

        <Button
            Name="CancelButton"
            Content="Cancel" 
            Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Margin="0,0,12,12"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="75" 
            IsCancel="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Codebehind:**

```cs
using System.Windows;
using TestProject.ViewModel;

namespace TestProject.Views
{
    public partial class OKCancelDialog : Window
    {
        private readonly OKCancelViewModel viewModel;

        //I use DI to inject the ViewModel into the View
        //This will allow you to use the view for different ViewModels if you need to.
        //Create an Interface for your ViewModel to implement to make ViewModel unit testing
        //easier. Testing frameworks such as rhino mock require Interfaces to test methods
        //in a class under test and it allows you to use an IoC Container to create the
        //ViewModel for you.                 
        public OpenReturnDialog(IOKCancelViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.viewModel = viewModel; //Do this if you need access to the VM from inside your View. Or you could just use this.Datacontext to access the VM.
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }

    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;


namespace TestProject.ViewModel
{
    public class OKCancelViewModel
    {
        public OKCancelViewModel()
        {
            OKButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(HandleOKButtonCommand, CanExecuteOKButtonCommand);
        }

        public DelegateCommand<object> OKButtonCommand { get; private set; }

        public void HandleOKButtonCommand(object obj)
        {
             //Here is where your code for OK button clicks go.

        }

        public bool CanExecuteOKButtonCommand(object obj)
        {
            //Put code to determine when the OK button will be enabled/disabled.
        } 

        //You may want to add a command for the Cancel button also if you have a need to 
        //enable/disable the cancel button
        //The command will look just like the OK button command above.
    }
}
```

Now, you will most likely want to have your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the event you have other controls in your UI that will bind to properties in the ViewModel.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply with code.I have just created a noddy project and put your code in it. I have 2 Windows .Your OKCancelDialog and MainWindow. MainWindow has a button "Launch Dialog . How do you do that with your code?

Comment: Well there is where peoples' opinions differ. I have yet to find a best-practice for that so I'll tell you how I do it. Your Main window should also have a VM with a "LaunchDialogCommand" - just like the commands in my code above. Insided the "HandleLaunchDialogCommand" you have code to create the OKCancelViewModel and OKCancelView. Something like this:  var dlg = new OKCancelView(new OKCancelViewModel());
Now, here is where many different opinions come in. You can call OKCancelView.ShowDialog(); but since you are inside a VM, most people feel it is wrong to call ShowDialog() inside a VM.

Comment: Most people in that case raise an event that some other class subscribes to and calls ShowDialog(). I’m a little laze so I usually just call ShowDialog() inside the ViewModel.
Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1730290/195356

Comment: OK.  Good so far, but how do you dismiss the view from the view model?  If the user hits OK, how does the view know it's time to exit, assuming we keep to the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 15):

I think everyone else that uses an IDialogService or actually creates their own dialogs is over engineering the problem. I really like the simplistic approach of using Funcs. Here is an example. First add this to your ViewModel:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /** Other ViewModel Code *//

    public Func<string, string, bool> OkCancelDialog { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you instantiate your derived class of your ViewModel, you just attach the following code: (I typically do this in the startup like Program.cs)

```
var myVM = new SomeSuperViewModel();
myVM.OkCancelDialog = (msg, caption) => MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, MessageBoxButton.OkCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK;
```

In your actual ViewModel code, all you have to do is call:

```
if (OkCancelDialog("Some crazy message.", "Caption"))
    //do something if true
else
    //else do something if false
```

In your unit tests you can do this:

```
var myVMToTest = new SomeSuperViewModel();
myVMToTest.OkCancelDialog = (msg, caption) => true; //could be false too if you need to test that functionality.
```

I prefer this approach, as it's simple and easy to test. What do other's think?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the **ViewModel** (EmailClient) sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to write custom dialogs with MVVM and it shows how you can use the MessageBox without violating the MVVM pattern.