# WPF databinding: Why doesn't my copy display on the screen?

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

What simple thing am I missing here? Why doesn't my copy display on the screen?

```
<Window x:Class="DeleteThis.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>

    <StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeCopy}" Height="35" Width="100" Margin="10"/>


    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and my code-behind.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    private string _someCopy;
    public string SomeCopy
    {
        get
        {
            return _someCopy;
        }

        set
        {
            _someCopy = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        SomeCopy = "why doesn't this display";
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers below are all correct. You should really get rid of the DP and use a ViewModel instead. Pass an instance of your VM into the View's constructor and assign the datacontext to the VM. You can see how I do it here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199162/ok-cancel-dialog-mvvm-pattern-wpf-how-can-i-do-it/4201604#4201604

Answer (score 3):

You never set the `DataContext` of the Window. Change your XAML to this...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Height="35" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
```

...and change your code behind to add the `DataContext` line...

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SomeCopy = "why doesn't this display";

        this.DataContext = SomeCopy;
    }
```

Your current issue has nothing to do with needing a `DependencyProperty` as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: He'll still need change notification.

Comment: @SLaks Change notification is not needed in this instance. Adding everything above, the value will display as the OP requests without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or making it a DP. If the OP wants to go further then the question at hand...then yes all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

WPF never finds out that the property changed.

To fix it, you can turn the property into a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

**EDIT**: You also need to bind to the property on the `Window` itself, like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeCopy, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ... />
```

Comment: @engwar: To see this move the `SomeCopy =` line in front of `InitializeComponent()`. Now SomeCopy will have a value before the TextBlock is created and it will get something from the binding.

Comment: -1 This is not the current problem, the DataContext is never set, it is null.

Comment: @Aaron: This is _a_ problem.  However, you're right; I missed that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks's answer is the correct one. But making dependency properties manually is annoying, so I link you to my favorite solution: [A custom PostSharp `NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute`](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/ui#data-binding) that, when used in conjunction with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), makes all the properties of any given class into dependency properties.

Comment: Normal `NotifyPropertyChanged` calls won't work on DependencyObjects.

Comment: @SLaks, can you expand on what you mean by that? I don't understand most aspects of that sentence, e.g. what's "normal" about `NotifyPropertyChanged` calls; what dependency objects have to do with dependency properties or with the OP or with what I posted, or why the two nouns in your post don't work together.

Comment: I don't think you can raise NotifyPropertyChanged events for non-dependency-properties in DependencyObjects (such as the `Window` class).  In other words, PostSharp won't help here.